# Fetch value from python dictionary and pass one by one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have dictionary as mentioned below.

```
a={'name':['test1','test2'],'regno':['123','345'],'subject':         
  ['maths','science'],'standard':['3','4']}
```

I need verify below things.

1. Each values count dictionary should be match.
2. Fetch the values from each keys one by one and pass it to my other function one by one.

---

```
  name = 'test1'   regno = '123'   subject='maths'   standard='3'
  name = 'test2'   regno = '345'   subject='science'   standard='4'
```

I have tried using below code but i am stuck here to find out exact way.

```
a={'name':['test1','test2'],'regno':['123','345'],'subject':['maths','science'],'standard':['3','4']}
lengths = [len(v) for v in a.values()]
    if (len(set(lengths)) <= 1) == True:
        print('All values are same')`
    else:
        print('All values are not same')
```

Need your help to fetch values one by one from each keys and pass it to a function.

Comment: yeah, it prints "All values are same" but you're actually testing that "all lists have the same length". What do you need ?

Comment: btw: `if (len(set(lengths)) <= 1) == True:` => `if len(set(lengths)) <= 1:`

Comment: I need to fetch values from dictionary and pass it to one by one  name = 'test1' regno = '123' subject='maths' standard='3' and name = 'test2' regno = '345' subject='science' standard='4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it done this way:

```
a={'name':['test1','test2'],'regno':['123','345'],'subject': 
['maths','science'],'standard':['3','4']}

w = [{'name':a['name'][i], 'regno':a['regno'][i], 'standard':a['standard'][i]} for i 
in range(len(a['name']))]

for x in range(len(w)):
    #your_func(w[x]['name'], w[x]['reno'], w[x]['standard'])
    print(w[x]['name'], w[x]['regno'], w[x]['standard'])
```

Comment: List comprehension for `w` looks heavy here, I would suggest using an explicit `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping over your dictionary items and then over the lists in values:

```
for key, vals_list in a.items():
    if len(set(vals_list)) <= 1:
        print(f'{key}: All values are same!')

    # Will do nothing if `vals_list` is empty
    for value in vals_list:
        your_other_func(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rebuild `a` into a list of dictionaries, and then use dict-unpacking to dynamically give the dictionary to the function instead:

```
def func(name, regno, subject, standard):
    print("name={}, regno={}, subject={}, standard={}".format(name, regno, subject, standard))

a={'name':['test1','test2'],'regno':['123','345',],'subject':         
  ['maths','science'],'standard':['3','4']}

new_a = [dict(zip(a.keys(), x)) for x in list(zip(*a.values()))]
print(new_a)

for d in new_a:
    func(**d)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'test1', 'regno': '123', 'subject': 'maths', 'standard': '3'}, {'name': 'test2', 'regno': '345', 'subject': 'science', 'standard': '4'}]
name='test1', regno='123', subject='maths', standard='3'
name='test2', regno='345', subject='science', standard='4'
```